# Inline comments and empty line in antlr4 grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

please can anyone explain me, what i need to change i this grammar to support inline comments (such as `// some text`) and empty line (which contains any number of space characters). I write following grammar, but this doesn't work.

```
program: line* EOF ;
line: (expression | assignment) (NEWLINE | EOF);
assignment : VARIABLE '=' expression ;
expression : '(' expression ')'                   #parenthesisExpression
           | '-' expression                       #unaryExpression
           | left=expression OP1 right=expression #firstPriorityExpression
           | left=expression OP2 right=expression #secondPriorityExpression
           | number=NUMBER                        #numericExpression
           | variable=VARIABLE                    #variableExpression
           ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
VARIABLE : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
OP1 : '*' | '/' ;
OP2 : '+' | '-' ;

NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;

WHITESPACE : [ \t\r]+ -> skip ;
COMMENT : '//' ~[\n\r]* -> skip ;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work?" Please elaborate. Also, does the `-` still work in an expression `-2-4`? I ask because you've changed your grammar how I suggested you do it.

Comment: yes, `-2-4` not working, they are interpreted as two separate unary expressions

Comment: Then that is the problem, and not the `COMMENT` rule, right?

Comment: Yes.`COMMENT` rule works fine when it appears after `expression` and `assignment` rules. But i need to support empty lines (only space characters and line comments)

Comment: Perhaps add `\n` to your `WHITESPACE` rule: `WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;` ?

Comment: Problem solved. I changed rule `line` to `('\n' | assignment ('\n' | EOF)  | expression ('\n' | EOF))`. Thank you anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The fact you added `-` in a parser rule as a literal token, and also made `OP2` match this character causes `OP2` to never match a `-`. You need to have a lexer rule that matches only the single minus sign ([as I showed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696045/extraneous-input-expecting-in-antlr4)):

```
op1
 : MUL
 | DIV
 ;

op2
 : ADD
 | MIN
 ;

...

MUL        : '*' ;
DIV        : '/' ;
ADD        : '+' ;
MIN        : '-' ;
```

and then use `MIN` in your unary alternative:

```
...
| MIN expression                       #unaryExpression
...
```

When you have a separate `MIN        : '-' ;` rule, you could do this:

```
...
| '-' expression                       #unaryExpression
...
```

because now ANTLR "knows" you mean the rule that matches a single `-`, but ANTLR does not "know" this when you have a lexer rule that matches a either a `-` or `+` like your `OP2` rule:

```
OP2 : '+' | '-' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation!